# highlight text in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to highlight the text in div by javascript function which takes the startindex and endindex as arguments.

**NOTE** : Everytime i call the function the previous highlight must be cleared.

I somehow made this

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="readPara">Sounds good, eh? So good that the ASP.NET team decided to incorporate the provider model for authentication (membership), roles, user profile, session and other aspects of the runtime into the ASP.NET 2.0 release in 2005. To capitalize on the provider model several new controls were added such as the CreateUserWizard, Login, ResetPassword and ChangePassword controls. These controls, given the provider model, could implement these features without knowing the details of the database being used.</div>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
function highlightWord(start,end){   
    $('.highLight').removeClass();
    var line = $('#readPara').text();
    console.log(line);
    if(end>line.length){
         end = line.length;   
    }   
    var newLine = line.substring(0,start) + "<span class='highLight'>" + line.substring(start,end) + "</span>" + line.substring(end,line.length);
    console.length(newLine);
    $('#readPara').contents().replaceWith(newLine);

}
```

Try to help me.

Comment: `console` doesn't have a `length` method. I'm assuming you mean `log()`

Comment: [Your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8H3D/4/). What problem are you having? (NB, I did adjust the class name in that example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : you don't need to remove `highLight` span as you are replacing all contents again. And replace html, that will take span as a html element.

```
function highlightWord(start,end){   
    var line = $('#readPara').text();
    console.log(line);
    if(end>line.length){
         end = line.length;   
    }   
    var newLine = line.substring(0,start) + "<span class='highLight'>" +
                  line.substring(start,end) + "</span>" 
                 + line.substring(end,line.length);
    console.log(newLine);
    $('#readPara').html(newLine);// replace newline here
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ebeUu/5/)**

Comment: Awesome Bro, Actually i some how figured it out yesterday only. But Still thanks for your valuable time and answer. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pratbhoir/n3h5A/ Have a loook  at it. I was trying to implement this :P

Comment: It is great and look nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebeUu/)

New line should be like this-

```
var newLine = line.substring(0,start) + "<span class='highLight'>" +
              line.substring(start,end) + "</span>" 
             + line.substring(end,line.length);
```